# Mocking Matcher with non native class

Tags: mockito, powermock

I am trying to write a @test in Junit using mockito and powermock. I have no issue stubbing methods that have no parameters. However when I try telling mockedBank to return true no matter what is passed into latePay, I get java.lang.NullPointerException. latePay is a final method that is why I am using powermock. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
    BankGenerator mockedBank = PowerMockito.mock(BankGenerator.class);
    when(mockedBank.latePay(Matchers.any(MoneyCalculator.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the correct annotations to your class containing the tests?

For example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassWithFinalMethod.class)
public class ClassContainingUnitTests {
...
}
```

I have used PowerMock with EasyMock in the past, and forgetting to include these annotations sometimes resulted in strange results.

For further reference, check here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806508/Using-PowerMockito-to-Mock-Final-and-Static-Method

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was it! The reason @test that had parameters worked were they were in a different test class in which I have RunWith & PrepareForTest. Facepalm

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help.